# How can i insert other option inside an option tag

Tags: html

I am trying to have a selection tag with some of this options in this order

House
   Bedroom
   Bathroom
   Kitchen

Technology
   Android
   Ios

but this doesnt seem to work

```
                   <select class="industry" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>industry</option>

                        <option value="">Home
                            <option value="">Bedroom</option>
                            <option value="">Bathroom</option>
                            <option value="">Kitchen</option>
                        </option>

                        <option value="">Technology
                            <option value="">Android</option>
                            <option value="">Ios</option>
                        </option>

                    </select>
```

is there a way to make it work?

Comment: `<option>` cannot be nested inside `<option>` You are probably looking for [optgroup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava  yes thats what I was looking for thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) for this

```html
<select class="industry" required>

    <option value="" disabled selected>industry</option>   
    
        <optgroup label="Home">
            <option value="">Bedroom</option>
            <option value="">Bathroom</option>
            <option value="">Kitchen</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Technology">
            <option value="">Android</option>
            <option value="">Ios</option>
        </optgroup>

</select>
```